# VB.NET Get Number Position Of Char In String (Index Of)

Tags: string, vb.net, indexing

im having a hard time getting a function working. I need to search message.text for each "," found, for each "," found I need to get the number position of where the "," is located in the string. For example: 23232,111,02020332,12 it would return 6/10/19 where the "," are located (index of). My code finds the first index of the first , but then just repeats 6 6 6 6 over, any help would be appreciated thanks.

Heres my code:

```
    For Each i As Char In message.Text
        If message.Text.Contains(",") Then
            Dim data As String = message.Text
            Dim index As Integer = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(data, ",").Index
            commas.AppendText(index & " ")
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it this way; instantiate a `Regex` object and increment each time the position from which you start the matching (this possibility is not available with the static method `Match`).

```
    Dim reg As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(",")
    Dim Index As Integer = reg.Match(data).Index
    Do While Index > 0
        commas.AppendText(index & " ")
        Index = reg.Match(data, Index + 1).Index
    Loop
```

p.s the returned indices are **zero-based**.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Regex.Matches method

```
    Dim message As String = "23232,111,02020332,12"
    Dim result As String = ""

    For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(message, ",")
        result &= m.Index + 1 & " "
    Next
```

I should also add that indexes are 0 based (which is why +1 is added to m.Index). If you later need these values to point to the position of a particular comma, you may be off by 1 and could potentially try to access an index larger than the actual string.